# Convert BigDecimal String to currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal

I have a pure string value which was obtained from a API call and is stored in a database as a string:

```
#<BigDecimal:7fabd9ba9618,'0.4173E2',18(18)>
```

This needs to be converted into a currency value somehow.

I would expect something like this to work, but it just returns as zero.

```
v = BigDecimal.new("#<BigDecimal:7fabd9ba9618,'0.4173E2',18(18)>")
return v.to_s('F')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have the _string_ `"#<BigDecimal:7fabd9ba9618,'0.4173E2',18(18)>"` in your database!? Are you sure that this is not a [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instance?

Comment: I think you need just second parameter. and also it is a string. So you need to extract the second parameter by split function

Comment: @Stefan - yes a bit bizarre - its an extract of a cached JSON array which is in my database (originally from an API call).

Comment: Is the API broken or your JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: why are those `BigDecimal`'s stored in `BigDecimal#inspect` representation in the DB? This is wrong and bad and should be fixed.

While the format seems to be documented in the ruby API it is probably not guaranteed to be persistent across versions.

I'd use a regexp to parse out the relevant part, just to be sure that I read the right things and get a proper error when the format does not match:

```
match = big_decimal_as_string.match(/#<BigDecimal:[a-f0-9]+,'([0-9E\.]+)',\d+\(\d+\)>/)
if match
  BigDecimal.new(match[1])
else
  raise "Could not parse #{big_decimal_as_string}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. You were right and I have reworked the architecture and now storing as tidy decimals in the DB. [Note to self - if its not easy; I'm probably doing it wrong]